# SqlDependency doesn't fire OnChange event when dataset is changed

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-services, sqldependency

I'm new to the concept of query notifications with SQL Server and it's going to take some time for me to wrap my head around it.

My objective is to create a Windows service application that is notified when a change has been made to a SQL Server table. I followed [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/555893) guide which was helpful in getting me started.

However I'm not able to get the expected result. The `OnStart()` method in my windows service app looks like so:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("Service Started");

        serviceRun = false;

        SqlClientPermission perm = new SqlClientPermission(System.Security.Permissions.PermissionState.Unrestricted);

        try
        {
            perm.Demand();
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("permission granted");
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("permission denied");
        }

        try
        {
            connstr = "Data Source=THSSERVER-LOCAL;Initial Catalog=ET;User ID=mujtaba;Password=ths123";

            connection = new SqlConnection(connstr);

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from dbo.Customer_FileUploads", connection);

            // Create a dependency and associate it with the SqlCommand.
            SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);

            // Maintain the reference in a class member.
            // Subscribe to the SqlDependency event.
            dependency.OnChange += Dependency_OnChange;

            SqlDependency.Start(connstr);

            connection.Open();

            // Execute the command.
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        //eventLog1.WriteEntry("reading data");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    eventLog1.WriteEntry("No rows found.");
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("Error Message: " + e.Message);
        }
}
```

The event `SqlDependency` is subscribed to, looks like so:

```
private void Dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    // Handle the event.
    eventLog1.WriteEntry("data changed");
}
```

The `OnStop()` method looks like so:

```
protected override void OnStop()
{
        SqlDependency.Stop(connstr);
        connection.Close();
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("In onStop.");
}
```

I have `ENABLE_BROKER` set to true in my database. The end result is, The service runs and the followings logs are created:

```
"Service Started"
"permission granted"
"data changed"
```

However when I insert new data into the table, the `OnChange()` event doesn't fire and no new log is created. Also when I stop and start the service again, the `OnChange()` is triggered even though there was no new data inserted.

Can anyone help me understand the process?

Comment: Happend the same to me, that got invalid notification info. It was because query was "SELECT 1 FROM database.squema.table", removing the database on query like "SELECT 1 FROM schema.table" solve the problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The SqlDependency is removed after the event fires so you need to execute the command again with the dependency.  Below is a console app example that will subscribe again unless the notification was due to an error.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace SqlDependencyExample
{
    class Program
    {

        static string connectionString = @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=YourDatabase;Application Name=SqlDependencyExample;Integrated Security=SSPI";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);

            getDataWithSqlDependency();

            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for data changes");
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to quit");
            Console.ReadLine();

            SqlDependency.Stop(connectionString);

        }

        static DataTable getDataWithSqlDependency()
        {

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM dbo.MyTable;", connection))
            {

                var dt = new DataTable();

                // Create dependency for this command and add event handler
                var dependency = new SqlDependency(cmd);
                dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(onDependencyChange);

                // execute command to get data
                connection.Open();
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection));

                return dt;

            }

        }

        // Handler method
        static void onDependencyChange(object sender,
           SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {

            Console.WriteLine($"OnChange Event fired. SqlNotificationEventArgs: Info={e.Info}, Source={e.Source}, Type={e.Type}.");

            if ((e.Info != SqlNotificationInfo.Invalid)
                && (e.Type != SqlNotificationType.Subscribe))
            {
                //resubscribe
                var dt = getDataWithSqlDependency();

                Console.WriteLine($"Data changed. {dt.Rows.Count} rows returned.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SqlDependency not restarted");
            }

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: This example is much simpler and easier to understand than Microsoft's own examples.

Comment: Should we unregister the event handler in onDependencyChange because a new SqlDependency instance is created eveny time the event occurrs and the handler is added to this new instance? i.e. `if (sender is SqlDependency dependency) dependency.OnChange -= onDependencyChange;`

Comment: @Alex, the SqlDependency is ephemeral. It doesn't fire again because the handler is removed when the event fires and all the QueryNotification stuff under the covers is torn down as well. I don't see any harm in removing the handler explicitly though since it's a no-op.