# How can i get notify when any new data insert/update/delete into my table with sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to run 1 windows/console application where it will listen to particular table for any changes insert/update/delete and when any thing happened in that table it will immediate notify in my application and on that basis i can perform actions.

I have tried `CLR Stored Procedure` but it is finish its transaction after it finishes the C# function. So i do not want to use this.

I have also tried https://github.com/christiandelbianco/monitor-table-change-with-sqltabledependency but as it is stopped after sometime even after preventing sql go to sleep.

Is there are any other solution or suggestion what i can use ?

Comment: Out of interest, any reason you have tagged 2 completely unsupported versions of SQL Server? There's a huge different between 2005 and 2008 (and again between 2008 and the supported versions). What version are you actually using? You could use DML triggers, but (personally) I feel the better way is to force the use of Stored Procedures for your DML operations, and then you can include your logging logic in there.

Comment: You can use [SqlDependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency?view=netframework-4.8). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41075211/sqldependency-doesnt-fire-onchange-event-when-dataset-is-changed) for a simple example.

Comment: @Larnu I am using sql server 2008

Comment: That still makes it not supported. It is ANCIENT.