# SqlDependency OnChange event not firing for SignalR

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, signalr, sqldependency

I know there are multiple questions on SO with a near identical subject, but unfortunately, after following countless guides and reading several answers, I'm at a loss to answer why this is occurring as a new user to SignalR / SqlDependencies.

I have an ASP.Net WebForms app that uses SignalR to push a realtime figure to the page. The code executes on initial load, and fires the event, but after that, I cannot get the event to fire when the dependency detects a change using the `OnChange` event.

I can see the Queue and SPs are created on the server just fine, but I can't ever see the queue receives any notifications when data is either added/removed or updated in the table. I think it may be something to do with the `OnChange` resubscription, but I'm not entirely sure.

What could be causing the event to not fire after initial load or the notification not be received from SQL?

I've posted all code below:

### Hub Code

```vb
Namespace SignalR.Models
    <HubName("notificationHub")>
    Public Class NotificationHub
        Inherits Hub

        Private notifCount As Integer

        <HubMethodName("sendNotifications")>
        Public Sub SendNotifications()
            Using db As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("aspCreate_fetch2").ConnectionString)
                Dim query As String = " SELECT IIF(COUNT(l.[id]) > 99, 99, COUNT(l.[id]))
                                      FROM pla.[lv_test] as l
                                     WHERE 1=1
                                          AND l.[lv_int_id] = 419"
                Using sp As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(query, db)
                    Dim dependency As SqlDependency = New SqlDependency(sp)
                    AddHandler dependency.OnChange, New OnChangeEventHandler(AddressOf dependency_OnChange)

                    sp.Notification = Nothing
                    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()

                    db.Open()

                    If db.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then db.Open()
                    Dim reader = sp.ExecuteReader()
                    dt.Load(reader)

                    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                        notifCount = Int32.Parse(dt.Rows(0)(0).ToString())
                    End If

                    Dim context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext(Of NotificationHub)()
                    context.Clients.All.ReceiveNotification(notifCount)
                End Using
            End Using
        End Sub
        Private Sub dependency_OnChange(sender As Object, e As SqlNotificationEventArgs)
            If e.Type = SqlNotificationType.Change Then
                SendNotifications()
            End If
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

### Global ASAX

```vb
    Sub Application_Start(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim sConn = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("redacted1").ConnectionString

        ' Fires when the application is started
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles)
        SqlDependency.[Stop](sConn)
        SqlDependency.Start(sConn)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Application_End(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim sConn = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("redacted1").ConnectionString
        SqlDependency.[Stop](sConn)
    End Sub
```

### JavaScript

```js
$(function () {
    var nf = $.connection.notificationHub;

    nf.client.receiveNotification = function (notifCount) {
        console.log("connection started");
        $("#notif-badge").text(notifCount);
    }

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        nf.server.sendNotifications();
    }).fail(function (e) {
        alert(e);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am no VB or Javascript expert but I believe that your subscription to OnChange is removed immediately after exiting SendNotifications().

In your code, you have the following dependencies:

SqlDependency -> SqlCommand -> SqlConnection

and you're getting attached to SqlDependency object. However, because your SqlConnection is disposed at the end of the method, your subscription is just gone.

Declare your SqlConnection as a private property and keep the connection open. Besides, move the event subscription to a separate initialization method or the constructor to do it only once.

**EDIT** :

Here is more or less what I have in mind (in C# , sorry ^^ ):

```cs
public class DemoSqlSubscriber : Hub
{  
    readonly string connectionString = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("aspCreate_fetch2").ConnectionString;  
    private SqlDependency dependency;
        
    public void StartListening()  
    {  
        SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);  
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);  
        connection.Open();  

        SqlCommand command=new SqlCommand();  
        command.CommandText= "SELECT [notification_count] FROM pla.[notif_count]";  
        command.Connection = connection;  
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;  

        dependency = new SqlDependency(command);  
        dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnCountChanged);  
    }  

    private void OnCountChanged(object s,SqlNotificationEventArgs e)  
    {  
        if(e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
        {
            // Publish 
            IHubContext<NotificationHub> context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
            context.Clients.All.ReceiveNotification(notifCount);
        }
    }  

    public void StopListening()  
    {  
        SqlDependency.Stop(connectionString);  
    }  
}
```

Could you try to structure your Hub accordingly in VB. NET and let us know ?

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I have removed the `Using` containers and left the connection open, but unfortunately, the `OnChange` routine still isn't ever hit in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the update/edit! This has fixed the issue and pointed out where my issue lied. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The query for notifications has many restrictions as detailed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms181122(v=sql.105)). One of the limitations is:

> The statement must not use any of the following aggregate functions:
> AVG, COUNT(*), MAX, MIN, STDEV, STDEVP, VAR, or VARP.

If the query is invalid for notification subscriptions, the `OnChange` handler will fire immediately with `SqlNotificationType.Invalid`.

Below are the `SqlNotificationEventArgs` property values I get when running a query similar to yours (i.e. with a `COUNT` aggregate function) when `OnChange` is invoked:

```
Info=Invalid, Source=Statement, Type=Subscribe
```

However, your handler code silently ignores the invalid subscription since it checks for only `SqlNotificationType.Change`.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I tried amending the query to `SELECT [notification_count] FROM pla.[notif_count]` - a test table I setup, and unfortunately, I get the same behaviour. The event initially fires, but the `dependency_OnChange` routine is never triggered. Not even on initial run. I can see messages on the queue on the server, but for whatever reason, the `OnChange` event just doesn't fire.

Comment: @RazorKillBen, [The notification is removed after the event fires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41075211/sqldependency-doesnt-fire-onchange-event-when-dataset-is-changed). You'll need to execute the query again with the dependency to get notified.